# Flex report printing for POS printer

Tags: apache-flex, printing

We are trying to print a restaurant bill to POS printer. We designed the bill in FLEX for a complete a4 size and managed to print that to the POS printer. I know that this is not the best practice. Could someone help us and let us know what is the best practice followed.

Below is the code that we used. A little help is greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:VBox xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
         xmlns:prints="printing.*"
         xmlns:ProComp="ProComp.*"
         xmlns:WrbComp="WrbComp.*"
         width="580" height="338" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()" fontSize="4"
         horizontalAlign="left" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
         implements="COM.pro.printing.IPrintableDocument" styleName="printPageStyle"
         verticalScrollPolicy="off">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <mx:NumberFormatter id="Rod2" precision="2" rounding="nearest" />
        <mx:NumberFormatter id="Rod4" precision="4" rounding="nearest" />
        <mx:NumberFormatter id="mxNumFormatter2"  useThousandsSeparator="true" thousandsSeparatorFrom="," precision="2" decimalSeparatorFrom="." />
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import COM.pro.printing.PrintPreviewControl;

            import Common.*;

            import WrbComp.BillCompKot;

            import flashx.textLayout.conversion.ConversionType;
            import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import mx.controls.AdvancedDataGrid;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.core.Application;
            import mx.events.PropertyChangeEvent;
            import mx.messaging.SubscriptionInfo;
            import mx.rpc.events.HeaderEvent;
            import mx.rpc.mxml.Concurrency;
            import mx.utils.StringUtil;

            [Bindable] public var accounts:ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable] public var currentPageNumber:Number = 1;
            [Bindable] public var pageCount:Number = 1;
            public var _parentObj:Object;
            public var _HdrArrCol:ArrayCollection;
            public var _DtlsArrCol:ArrayCollection;
            static var gridheight:int=0;
            public var _DtlsArrOrd:ArrayCollection;
            public var _DtlsArrPrd:ArrayCollection;
            public var items:Number;
            public var qty:int;
            public var Title:String = "";
            public var TinNo:String = "";
            public var Address1:String="";
            public var Address2:String="";
            public var Address3:String="";
            public var PrintWidth:Number=0;
            public var TitleFontSize:Number=0;
            public var AddressFontsize:Number=0;
            public var OtherFontsize:Number=0;
            public var BillNoFontsize:Number=0;
            public var BillTitleFontsize:Number=0;

            var myXML:XMLDocument=new XMLDocument();
            var GrnXML:XMLDocument=new XMLDocument();

            public var Pnt:COM.pro.printing.PrintPreviewControl=new COM.pro.printing.PrintPreviewControl();

            private function fakeData():ArrayCollection
            {
                var COUNT:int = 70;
                var ar:Array = [];
                for (var i:int=0; i<COUNT; ++i)
                {
                    ar.push(
                        {
                            'account':i+1,
                            'control':COUNT-i-1,
                            'description':'Account ' + (i+1).toString()
                        }
                    );
                }
                return new ArrayCollection(ar);
            }            
            private function ReadRep_XML()
            {
                //                var file:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + "\\Config.xml");
                //                var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
                //                fileStream.open(file,FileMode.READ)
                //                var Content:String=fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable)
                //                myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
                //                myXML.parseXML(Content);
            }
            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {            
                if(_HdrArrCol.length > 0)
                {                
                    accounts = fakeData();

                    lbl_title1.text=_HdrArrCol[0].Title6;
                    lbl_title2.text=_HdrArrCol[0].Title7;
                    //            lbl_Street.text=_HdrArrCol[0].Street;
                    //            lbl_Addres.text=_HdrArrCol[0].Address;
                    //            lbl_City.text=_HdrArrCol[0].City;
                    //    lbl_title3.text=_HdrArrCol[0].City+" - "+_HdrArrCol[0].Pincode+", Ph : "+_HdrArrCol[0].PhoneNumber;
                    if(_HdrArrCol[0].TinNumber!="")
                    {
                        //        lbl_title4.text="TIN No : "+_HdrArrCol[0].TinNumber;
                    }                    
                //    HT_CUSNAM.text = "Name : "+_HdrArrCol[0].GuestName;
                    //    Cus_Add.text = "Address : "+_HdrArrCol[0].City;
                    //        HT_DocNo.text = "Bill No:"+_HdrArrCol[0].BillNo;
                    //        HT_Billtype.text = "Bill Type : "+_HdrArrCol[0].Type;
                    //        Cus_Mob.text="Contact No : "+_HdrArrCol[0].MobileNo;
                    HT_Room.text="TableNo : "+_HdrArrCol[0].TableNo;
                    HT_DocDt.text ="Date         : "+_HdrArrCol[0].Date;
                    var timestr:String=_HdrArrCol[0].Time;
                    HT_Time.text ="Time      : "+timestr.substr(0,5);
                    //        HT_User.text ="User : "+_HdrArrCol[0].UserName;
                    //                    HT_Pax.text = "  Pax :"+_HdrArrCol[0].Pax;
                    //        lbl_SubTotal.text = _HdrArrCol[0].SubTotal;                        
                    //        lbl_ServiceTax.text=_HdrArrCol[0].ServiceTax;                        
                    //lbl_Rounding.text=_HdrArrCol[0].RoundingOff;
                    //    lbl_totalround.text=_HdrArrCol[0].TotalRounded;                        
                    //        lbl_Total.text=_HdrArrCol[0].Total;
                    lbl_KOT.text="K O T No : "+_HdrArrCol[0].KotNo;
                    lbl_Waiter.text = "Waiter      : "+_HdrArrCol[0].WaiterName;
                    //lbl_Vat.text=_HdrArrCol[0].VatAmount;
                    //lbl_DiscountAmt.text=_HdrArrCol[0].DiscountAmt;
                    //lbl_total.text=_HdrArrCol[0].Gross;
                    //lbl_PackageCost.text=_HdrArrCol[0].PackageCost;                        
                    //lbl_ECESS.text=_HdrArrCol[0].ECESS;    
                    //            lbl_Total1.text=_HdrArrCol[0].Total;

                }
                else
                {
                    Alert.show("No Data Available For Print");
                }                
                fnPrintGridSetup();
                layoutDocument();


            }            
            private function focusOut_Round2(CtrlNm:String)
            {
                this[CtrlNm].text=Rod2.format(this[CtrlNm].text)

            }
            private function fnPrintGridSetup():void
            {

                    //printADG.dataProvider = _DtlsArrCol;
                    var gridlen:int=_DtlsArrCol.length;

                    GridHeader.fnSetHeader("Item","Qty");
                    for(var linecnt:int=0;linecnt<gridlen; linecnt++){

                        var lineItem:BillCompKot= new BillCompKot();

                        lineItem.width = this.width-10;                  
                        lineItem.fnSetProps(_DtlsArrCol[linecnt].ProductName,
                            _DtlsArrCol[linecnt].Quantity);                      
                        lineItemGrp.addElement(lineItem);
                        items=linecnt+1;
                        qty= qty+int( _DtlsArrCol[linecnt].Quantity);        
                        lineItemGrp.height = lineItemGrp.height + 20;
                        var str:String=_DtlsArrCol[linecnt].ProductName;
                        /*if(str.length>15)
                        {
                            lineItemGrp.height = lineItemGrp.height+70;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lineItemGrp.height = lineItemGrp.height+30;
                        }*/
                    }

                    this.height = 310+ lineItemGrp.height;            
                HT_ItemsNo.text="Items     : "+String(gridlen);
            }

            private function layoutDocument():void
            {
                //printADG.percentHeight = 100;

                validateNow();

                calculatePageCount();
            }

            public function get desiredWidth():Number
            {
                return this.width;
            }

            public function get desiredHeight():Number
            {
                //var desiredheight:Number=Number(gridheight);
                var desiredheight:Number=this.height;
                return desiredheight;

            }

            public function set parentObj(obj:Object):void
            {
                _parentObj = obj;
            }
            public function set HdrArrCol(HAC:ArrayCollection):void
            {
                _HdrArrCol = HAC;
            }
            public function set DtlsArrCol(DAC:ArrayCollection):void
            {
                _DtlsArrCol = DAC;
                var gridlen:int=_DtlsArrCol.length;
                gridheight=400+(20*gridlen);

            }


            [Bindable(event="validPagesChanged")]
            public function get validNextPage():Boolean
            {
                // FIXME PLEASE : sometimes printADG.validNextPage returns false
                // even though it's not on the last page. Yet, if I disable the
                // check for printADG.validNextPage and just use my calculated
                // page numbers, everything displays and prints correctly, despite
                // going beyond what it considers its last page.
                //return printADG.validNextPage /* && currentPageNumber < pageCount*/;
                return false
            }

            public function displayObject():DisplayObject
            {
                return this;
            }                    

            public function nextPage():void
            {
                //                if ( pageCount != currentPageNumber + 1 )
                //                {
                //                    xfooter.visible = false;    
                //                }
                //                else
                //                {
                //                    xfooter.visible = true;    
                //                }

                //printADG.nextPage();
                currentPageNumber++;

                /*if(currentPageNumber == 2)
                {
                removeHeaderFromLayout();
                }*/

                validateNow();
                dispatchEvent(new Event("validPagesChanged"));

            }

            [Bindable(event="validPagesChanged")]
            public function get validPreviousPage():Boolean
            {
                /* see note for validNextPage */
                //return printADG.validPreviousPage /* && currentPageNumber > 1*/;
                return false
            }

            public function previousPage():void
            {
                //                if ( pageCount != currentPageNumber - 1 )
                //                {
                //                    xfooter.visible = false;    
                //                }
                //                else
                //                {
                //                    xfooter.visible = true;    
                //                }

                //printADG.previousPage();
                currentPageNumber--;

                if (currentPageNumber == 1)
                {
                    includeHeaderInLayout();
                }
                validateNow();
                dispatchEvent(new Event("validPagesChanged"));

            }

            public function calculatePageCount():void
            {
                var count:Number=1;
                /*
                while(printADG.validNextPage)
                {
                count++;
                if(count == 2)
                {
                removeHeaderFromLayout();
                }
                printADG.nextPage();
                validateNow();
                }*/
                pageCount = count;
                moveToFirstPage();
            }

            public function moveToFirstPage():void
            {
                currentPageNumber = 1;
                //printADG.moveToFirstPage();
                includeHeaderInLayout();
                validateNow();
                dispatchEvent(new Event("validPagesChanged"));
            }


            private function removeHeaderFromLayout():void
            {
                //header.includeInLayout = false;
                // force a re-calc
                //printADG.percentHeight = 99;
                //printADG.percentHeight = 100;
            }

            private function includeHeaderInLayout():void
            {
                //header.includeInLayout = true;
                // force a re-calc
                //printADG.percentHeight = 99;
                //printADG.percentHeight = 100;
            }


        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Group x="2" y="2" width="98%" height="338">    
        <s:VGroup height="333" width="100%" gap="3" y="0" x="23">
            <s:VGroup width="98%" height="87" id="Header" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="bottom" chromeColor="#060303" contentBackgroundColor="#FCFBFB" >                    

                <s:Label id="lbl_title1" x="42" y="3" width="474" height="55" fontSize="60"
                         fontWeight="bold" textAlign="center" fontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
                <s:Label id="lbl_title2" x="97" y="44" width="363" height="20" fontSize="25"
                         fontWeight="bold" textAlign="center" fontFamily="Times New Roman"/>                
            </s:VGroup>            
            <s:Line width="90%" height="0" >
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="black" weight="2" />
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>                        
            <s:VGroup width="98%" height="30" gap="1">
                <s:HGroup height="100%" width="100%" gap="60">
                    <s:Label id="lbl_KOT" width="250" height="100%" fontSize="30" text="K O T No : 145263" 
                             textAlign="left" verticalAlign="top" fontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
                    <s:Label id="HT_Room" width="180" verticalAlign="top" fontFamily="Times New Roman" 
                             height="100%" fontSize="30" text="Table No : 14"/>
                </s:HGroup>                
            </s:VGroup>
            <s:VGroup width="98%" height="30" gap="1">
                <s:HGroup height="100%" width="100%" gap="3">    
                    <s:Label id = "HT_DocDt" width="307" verticalAlign="top" fontFamily="Times New Roman"  
                             height="100%" textAlign="left" fontSize="30" text="Date         : 14/02/2014"/>
                    <s:Label id = "HT_Time" width="210" verticalAlign="top" fontFamily="Times New Roman"  
                             height="100%" textAlign="left" fontSize="30" text="Time       : 15:20"/>
                </s:HGroup>                
            </s:VGroup>     
            <s:VGroup width="98%" height="30" gap="1">
                <s:HGroup height="100%" width="100%" gap="1">    
                    <s:Label id="lbl_Waiter" width="315" height="100%" fontSize="30" fontFamily="Times New Roman"
                             textAlign="left" verticalAlign="top" text="Waiter      : fgdhfghfghfg"/>
                    <s:Label id = "HT_ItemsNo" width="178" verticalAlign="top" fontFamily="Times New Roman"  
                             height="100%" textAlign="left" fontSize="30" text="Items      : 99"/>
                </s:HGroup>                
            </s:VGroup>                
            <WrbComp:BillCompKot id="GridHeader" width="98%" height="30"/>        
            <s:Line width="90%" height="0" >
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="black" weight="2" />
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>            
            <s:VGroup width="98%"  id="lineItemGrp" gap="2">
            </s:VGroup>
            <s:Line width="90%" height="0" >
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="black" weight="2" />
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>    
            <s:HGroup width="98%" height="50" gap="0">
                <s:VGroup width="98%" height="100%" gap="0">                    
                    <s:HGroup height="44" width="100%" gap="80" verticalAlign="bottom" >
                        <s:Label text="" width="50%" height="25" fontFamily="Times New Roman" fontWeight="bold" verticalAlign="top" fontSize="25" x="130" y="0" textAlign="left"/> 
                        <s:Label width="146" height="25" fontSize="25" fontFamily="Times New Roman" fontWeight="bold" text="CASHIER"
                                 textAlign="right" verticalAlign="top"/>                
                    </s:HGroup>                                            
                </s:VGroup>
            </s:HGroup>            
            <s:Line width="90%" height="0" >
                <s:stroke>
                    <s:SolidColorStroke color="black" weight="2" />
                </s:stroke>
            </s:Line>
        </s:VGroup>
    </s:Group>
</mx:VBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used system.drawing.printing dll and converted all the content to XML. Done. Issue solved after long research. Thanks to Shameem and Arun in our team to have put their effort to solve this.

Sample codes, that we used.

```
XmlDocument dc = new XmlDocument();
            dc.LoadXml(Dtls);
            int len = dc.SelectNodes("//GridXml").Count;
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pdoc = new PrintDocument();
            PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
            Font font = new Font("Courier New", 15);
            PaperSize psize = new PaperSize("Custom", 300, 300);
            pd.Document = pdoc;
            pd.Document.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = psize;
            // 230 + (len * 15) KOT
            // 410+(len*15) - Bill
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Height = 230 + (len * 15) + 410 + (len * 15);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.Width = 300;
            pdoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
            //pdoc.Print();
            PrintDialog printdlg = new PrintDialog();
            PrintPreviewDialog printPrvDlg = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPrvDlg.Document = pdoc;
            printPrvDlg.ShowDialog(); // this shows the preview and then show the Printer Dlg below
            printdlg.Document = pdoc;
            if (printdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pdoc.Print();
            }
        }
```